# Not able to click on list elements

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, html-lists

Clicking on "li" gives element is not clickable. Click action is not working on span or div for 'Yes' and 'No' options. Please suggest a better way.
The user needs to answer Yes or No for a question. The options are presented in li elements

Here is the code snippet:

```
<div class="question">
<span>Did one of our current shoppers refer you to apply?
<span class="asterisk">*</span>
</span>
</div>

<div class="content">
<div class="content-wrapper">
<div class="attachment-wrapper">
<div class="control">
<ul class="keys">
<li class="container step0" style="width: 69px;">
<div class="aux " style="opacity: 1;">
<div class="bg"></div>
<div class="bd"></div>
</div>
<div class="letter"><span>Y</span></div>
<span class="label">Yes</span>
<span class="tick"></span>
</li>

<li class="container step0 selected" style="width: 69px;">
<div class="aux " style="opacity: 1;">
<div class="bg"></div>
<div class="bd"></div>
</div>
<div class="letter"><span>N</span></div>
<span class="label">No</span>
<span class="tick"></span>
</li>
</ul>

</div>
</div>
<div class="clear"></div>
<div class="message "><span></span><div></div></div>

</div>
</div>
```

Action performed: Clicking on 'No' within span element

```
WebElement refer = 
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated
(By.xpath("//li[@id='45182998']/div/div[3]/div/div[1]/div/ul/li[2]/span[1]"
)));
action.moveToElement(refer).click().build().perform();
```

exception :

```
org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Timed out after 20 seconds waiting for visibility of element located by By.xpath: //li[@id='45182998']/div/div[3]/div/div[1]/div/ul/li[2]/span[1]
```

[This is what the question looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i1FtZ.jpg)

Comment: Share your code and exception log. Describe the actions sequence you need to perform on page as user. Also add programming language tag

Comment: Please give a screenshot of the options

Answer (score 0):

There are several elements (as below list) which possible to response to your click, so you need to find out which one by manually.

- `<li class="container`
- `<div class="letter"><span>`
- `<span class="label">`

Open Chrome's DevTool, In `Element` tab, inspect one element from above 3 elements , choose the HTML node of the element, then switch to the `Console` tab and execute `$0.click()` to click the element , if the option choosen after click, means you should click on it rather than the other 2 elements. If option not choosen, repeat steps on next element of the 3 elements.

I guess should click on `<li class="container`

```
// click 'Yes' 
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div.attachment-wrapper ul.keys > li:nth-child(1) span.label"))

// click 'No'
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div.attachment-wrapper ul.keys > li:nth-child(2) span.label"))
```

If your script still fail even you had found the correct element, try add some sleep() before click(), if sleep work, means you need to wait for a moment for the options load into page, thus replace sleep() to wait()

Comment: Clicking on <li class="container works randomly . Other times it fails  giving Element is not clickable at (co ordinates)

Comment: I update my code to change to click the `<span class="label">` inside `li`, you can give a try

Answer (score 0):

As per the given *HTML* to click on **Yes** you have to induce *WebDriverWait* with *ExpectedConditions* clause as *elementToBeClickable* and your can use the following code block :

```
new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//div[@class='content']//div[@class='control']/ul[@class='keys']/li//span[@class='tick']"))).click();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try once changing the xpath to below and perform click action:

```
//*[starts-with(@class, 'label') and contains(text(), 'No')]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try JavascriptExecutor

```
JavascriptExecutor je = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("--Path--"));
je.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);",element);
element.click();
```

This worked for me.